# docker не может выполнить скрипт

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: PyCharm]

Я хочу в скрипте сделать миграции, добавляю его в папку, но когда в Dockerfile запускаю через entrypoint его выполнение, то пишет, что не видит scrypt.sh все инструкции до этого момента исполняются без ошибок (вроде бы) хотелось бы понять в чем моя ошибка и как сделать правильно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Workdir уже задаёт текущий каталог app. Или его уберите, или app в entrypoint

Comment: Попробовал, но то ли не то сделал, то ли не сработало(

Comment: Скрины в основной вопрос залил

Comment: На первом скришоте сконфигурировано правильно. В чём проблема?

Comment: В общем всем спасибо, я как то иначе немного по итогу решил, я помню только, что в этих скринах он у меня скрипт sh просто не видел